# Selecting some columns and assigning properties to columns in a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, annotations, tidyr, tibble

In my mind, when I deal with a data frame, I like to consider that I may have subgroups of rows and subgroups of columns that I may want to distinguish or to refer to later in my analysis —for instance: those individuals that meet a given condition (this is a subgroup of rows); those variables meeting a certain condition (this is a subgroup of columns).

When I want to select a subgroup of columns from a data frame in R, I do things like these:

```
# `my.data` is a data frame.

# Here I select some columns to use them later:

selected.data = my.data[ ,11:19]

# Here it is another example, where I process a subset of columns:

for(i in 11:19) {
    # Here I do things with column `my.data[ ,i]`
}
```

I would like to do this in a more general way, so that I don't need to specify the range of columns. So: **What is the most direct, simple way to define (and use) subgroups of columns meeting a given property in R?**

Examples of possible uses: I want to select those columns from a data set such that...

- ... they are categorical variables.
- ... they are eligible for a certain analysis (for instance, let's say I want to consider them as explanatory variables for a regression analysis).
- ...

So, the question really is:

- **How can I define subgroups of columns? I mean, how can I give a name to a certain subset of columns, so that I can refer to it later?**
- **Alternatively, can I define custom column properties?** In this way, I could do things like: select columns such that `property.1 == 'YES'`.

I hope this question does not sound too naïve to you.

Comment: @akrun I think the users who answered got my point.

Answer (score 2):

Very simply, you can assign indices or names to objects. Using the `diamonds` data built in to the `ggplot2` package:

```
library(ggplot2)

(diam = head(diamonds))
#> # A tibble: 6 x 10
#>   carat cut       color clarity depth table price     x     y     z
#>   <dbl> <ord>     <ord> <ord>   <dbl> <dbl> <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 0.23  Ideal     E     SI2      61.5    55   326  3.95  3.98  2.43
#> 2 0.21  Premium   E     SI1      59.8    61   326  3.89  3.84  2.31
#> 3 0.23  Good      E     VS1      56.9    65   327  4.05  4.07  2.31
#> 4 0.290 Premium   I     VS2      62.4    58   334  4.2   4.23  2.63
#> 5 0.31  Good      J     SI2      63.3    58   335  4.34  4.35  2.75
#> 6 0.24  Very Good J     VVS2     62.8    57   336  3.94  3.96  2.48

# columns with dimensions of the diamonds
dim_cols = c("x", "y", "z")  ## could also use numbers

# numeric columns
(num_cols = sapply(diamonds, is.numeric))
#>   carat     cut   color clarity   depth   table   price       x       y       z 
#>    TRUE   FALSE   FALSE   FALSE    TRUE    TRUE    TRUE    TRUE    TRUE    TRUE

## could use num_cols as-is, 
## or convert to column numbers with which(num_cols)
## or to names with names(num_cols)[num_cols]

diam[dim_cols]
#> # A tibble: 6 x 3
#>       x     y     z
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1  3.95  3.98  2.43
#> 2  3.89  3.84  2.31
#> 3  4.05  4.07  2.31
#> 4  4.2   4.23  2.63
#> 5  4.34  4.35  2.75
#> 6  3.94  3.96  2.48

# log the dimensions
diam[dim_cols] = lapply(diam[dim_cols], log)

diam
#> # A tibble: 6 x 10
#>   carat cut       color clarity depth table price     x     y     z
#>   <dbl> <ord>     <ord> <ord>   <dbl> <dbl> <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 0.23  Ideal     E     SI2      61.5    55   326  1.37  1.38 0.888
#> 2 0.21  Premium   E     SI1      59.8    61   326  1.36  1.35 0.837
#> 3 0.23  Good      E     VS1      56.9    65   327  1.40  1.40 0.837
#> 4 0.290 Premium   I     VS2      62.4    58   334  1.44  1.44 0.967
#> 5 0.31  Good      J     SI2      63.3    58   335  1.47  1.47 1.01 
#> 6 0.24  Very Good J     VVS2     62.8    57   336  1.37  1.38 0.908

## same thing works for rows
favorite_rows = c(1, 3, 4)

diam[favorite_rows, ]
#> # A tibble: 3 x 10
#>   carat cut     color clarity depth table price     x     y     z
#>   <dbl> <ord>   <ord> <ord>   <dbl> <dbl> <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 0.23  Ideal   E     SI2      61.5    55   326  1.37  1.38 0.888
#> 2 0.23  Good    E     VS1      56.9    65   327  1.40  1.40 0.837
#> 3 0.290 Premium I     VS2      62.4    58   334  1.44  1.44 0.967
```

<sup>Created on 2020-12-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

However, the nice new-ish way to do operations on groups of columns is with `dplyr`'s `across()` and `tidyselect` selection helpers (since `dplyr` version 1.0). This allows for things like this:

```
library(dplyr)
# log all numeric columns
# and add 1 to  dimension columns
diam %>%
  mutate(
    across(where(is.numeric), log),
    across(all_of(dim_cols), ~ . + 1)
  )
```

And this comes with other benefits of `dplyr`, like that grouped operations are trivial. I'd strongly recommend reading the [Introduction to dplyr vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/dplyr.html), and for this topic especially, the [colwise dplyr vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/colwise.html).

Comment: Yeah, had to pause mid-updates for a meeting, and didn't reload before finishing. I'll leave it in if you don't mind -- I think the discussion and vignette links are valuable.

Comment: (But also upvoted your answer, of course. It's direct and to-the-point)

Answer (score 1):

In tidyverse, we can use `mutate` with `across` without creating a new subset of data.

```
library(dplyr)
iris1 <- iris %>% 
      mutate(across(where(is.numeric), log))
```

-output

```
head(iris1)
#  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
#1     1.629241    1.252763    0.3364722  -1.6094379  setosa
#2     1.589235    1.098612    0.3364722  -1.6094379  setosa
#3     1.547563    1.163151    0.2623643  -1.6094379  setosa
#4     1.526056    1.131402    0.4054651  -1.6094379  setosa
#5     1.609438    1.280934    0.3364722  -1.6094379  setosa
#6     1.686399    1.360977    0.5306283  -0.9162907  setosa
```

---

If we need to subset columns, can use `select`

```
iris_sub <- iris %>%
               select(where(is.numeric))
```